# How to pop up an on screen keyboard to enter some data in an entry gadget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter GUI app. I am using a raspberry pi with a touch screen. Raspberry pi's virtual keyboard creates many chaos. So I was thinking of an automatic keypad.  There are some entry fields. Is it possible to do something like when the user clicks the entry field, a key pad (just numbers) pop up and then the user can use that key pad to enter values in entry field. I just need numbers from 0 to 9 and (.). Is it even possible to do it in tkinter? Any suggestions?

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')

container_1 = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=2, relief="solid")
set_1 = tk.Label(container_1, text = "min Current")
set_1.grid(row=3, column=9)

set_2 = tk.Label(container_1, text = "max Current")
set_2.grid(row=4, column=9)

enter_set_1 =tk.Entry(container_1, width=12) #entry fields, need a keypad here
enter_set_1.grid(row=3, column=10)

enter_set_2 =tk.Entry(container_1, width=12)
enter_set_2.grid(row=4, column=10)

container_1.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="x", padx=10, pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You'll have to create tk buttons then grab and insert their values as the user clicks them. Either you fix the buttons on a location in the main root window or you create a bind to the entry boxes that generates the buttons when the cursor enters the entry.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just make a frame of buttons and `place` it anywhere you want.

Comment: first create Frame with Buttons. Next you can bind() to Entry function which will display this Frame using `place()`. This function would have to get reference to Entry to put values from buttons - and this may need more works - but first you need frame with buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simple example uses `Button` near `Entry` to open `Frame` with `keypad`. It also assigns `Entry` to variable `target` which buttons use to put text in correct `Entry`.

It uses `place` to put `keypad` in center of window.

It would need more work to open keypad when you click on `Entry` and display it nearer `Entry`.

[image]

Using `Class` you could create widget `Keypad`.

```
import tkinter as tk

def create_keypad(root):
    keypad = tk.Frame(root)

    for y in range(3):
        for x in range(3):
            val = y*3 + x
            text = str(val)
            b = tk.Button(keypad, text=text, command=lambda txt=text:insert_text(txt))
            b.grid(row=y, column=x, sticky='news')

    x = tk.Button(keypad, text='Hide', command=hide_keypad)
    x.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='news')

    return keypad

def insert_text(text):
    target.insert('end', text)

def show_keypad(widget):
    global target
    target = widget

    keypad.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='c')

def hide_keypad():
    global taget
    target = None

    keypad.place_forget()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')

keypad = create_keypad(root)
target = None

f = tk.Frame(root)
f.pack()

e1 = tk.Entry(f)
e1.grid(row=0, column=0)
b1 = tk.Button(f, text='Keypad', command=lambda:show_keypad(e1))
b1.grid(row=0, column=1)

e2 = tk.Entry(f)
e2.grid(row=1, column=0)
b2 = tk.Button(f, text='Keypad', command=lambda:show_keypad(e2))
b2.grid(row=1, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** I put code in Class so now it is widget. It has buttons "Clear", "Backspace", and memory "Copy", "Paste" but it doesn't use clipboard.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- classes ---

class Keypad(tk.Frame):

    cells = [
        ['1', '2', '3'],
        ['4', '5', '6'],
        ['7', '8', '9'],
        ['0', '.', '-'],
    ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.target = None
        self.memory = ''

        for y, row in enumerate(self.cells):
            for x, item in enumerate(row):
                b = tk.Button(self, text=item, command=lambda text=item:self.append(text))
                b.grid(row=y, column=x, sticky='news')

        x = tk.Button(self, text='Backspace', command=self.backspace)
        x.grid(row=0, column=10, sticky='news')

        x = tk.Button(self, text='Clear', command=self.clear)
        x.grid(row=1, column=10, sticky='news')

        x = tk.Button(self, text='Copy', command=self.copy)
        x.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky='news', columnspan='3')

        x = tk.Button(self, text='Paste', command=self.paste)
        x.grid(row=9, column=10, sticky='news')

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='memory:')
        self.label.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=11, sticky='news')

        x = tk.Button(self, text='Hide', command=self.hide)
        x.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=11, sticky='news')


    def get(self):
        if self.target:
            return self.target.get()

    def append(self, text):
        if self.target:
            self.target.insert('end', text)

    def clear(self):
        if self.target:
            self.target.delete(0, 'end')

    def backspace(self):
        if self.target:
            text = self.get()
            text = text[:-1]
            self.clear()
            self.append(text)

    def copy(self):
        #TODO: copy to clipboad
        if self.target:
            self.memory = self.get()
            self.label['text'] = 'memory: ' + self.memory
            print(self.memory)

    def paste(self):
        #TODO: copy from clipboad
        if self.target:
            self.append(self.memory)

    def show(self, entry):
        self.target = entry

        self.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='c')

    def hide(self):
        self.target = None

        self.place_forget()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')

keypad = Keypad(root)

f = tk.Frame(root)
f.pack()

e1 = tk.Entry(f)
e1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
b1 = tk.Button(f, text='Keypad', command=lambda:keypad.show(e1))
b1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='news')

e2 = tk.Entry(f)
e2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='news')
b2 = tk.Button(f, text='Keypad', command=lambda:keypad.show(e2))
b2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='news')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: cool solution. added 9 and (.) to above solution.  Trying to implement backspace and some validation methods. Thank you so much.

Comment: for backspace you have to get full text from entry,remove last char from text, clear entry and put full new text in entry.

Comment: validation you can assign directly to `Entry` and you don't have to change keypad. Some examples with validation but without description: [furas/python-examples/tkinter/validate](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/validate)

Comment: on GitHub I put code which has all in Class so now it is widget. It also has buttons "Clear", "Backspace", and memory "Copy", "Paste" but it doesn't use clipboard. [furas/python-examples/tkinter/keypad](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/keypad)

Answer (score 0):

```
#method to add backspace button to above solution

backspacebtn= tkinter.Button(keypad, text='Back', command=lambda:fn_back())
backspacebtn.grid(row=1, columnspan=1)

def fn_back():
    global target
    val = target.get()
    new_val= val[:-1]
    target.delete(0,tk.END)
    target.insert(0,new_val)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer's anything. Please elaborate more when you are answering. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @mchawre '*This doesn't answer anything*': That's not entirely true... And an (even short) code-only answer [isn't considered very low quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/8376184)...