# Typing on entry using virtual keyboard in another python program

Tags: python, tkinter, virtual-keyboard

I'm having a problem with typing into my Tkinter entry. I did a registration code and with every entry on my code calls a virtual keyboard, the virtual keyboard is separated python program. I successfully called another python program but I can't type on my Tkinter entry which is my main program using the virtual keyboard I called.
Is there any way to get this done? 
here is my code

```
    def register(self):
    self.master_register = Toplevel()

    self.first_name = StringVar()
    self.middle_name = StringVar()
    self.last_name = StringVar()
    self.sex = StringVar()
    self.birth_day = StringVar()
    self.civil_status = StringVar()

    self.label_head = Label(self.master_register, text = "Please fill up all informations below")
    self.label_head.pack()

    self.label_first_name = Label(self.master_register, text = "First Name")
    self.label_first_name.pack()
    self.entry_first_name = Entry(self.master_register, textvariable = self.first_name)
    self.entry_first_name.pack()
    self.entry_first_name.bind('<ButtonPress-1>',self.keyboard)

    self.label_middle_name = Label(self.master_register, text = "Middle Name")
    self.label_middle_name.pack()
    self.entry_middle_name = Entry(self.master_register, textvariable = self.middle_name)
    self.entry_middle_name.pack()
    self.entry_middle_name.bind('<ButtonPress-1>',self.keyboard)

    self.label_last_name = Label(self.master_register, text = "Last Name")
    self.label_last_name.pack()
    self.entry_last_name = Entry(self.master_register, textvariable = self.last_name)
    self.entry_last_name.pack()
    self.entry_last_name.bind('<ButtonPress-1>',self.keyboard)

    self.label_sex = Label(self.master_register, text = "Sex")
    self.label_sex.pack()
    self.radio_button_sex1 = Radiobutton(self.master_register, text = "Male", variable = self.sex, value = "Male" )
    self.radio_button_sex1.pack()
    self.radio_button_sex2 = Radiobutton(self.master_register, text = "Female", variable = self.sex, value = "Female")
    self.radio_button_sex2.pack()


    self.label_birthday = Label(self.master_register, text = "Birth Day")
    self.label_birthday.pack()
    self.entry_birthday = Entry(self.master_register, textvariable = self.birth_day)
    self.entry_birthday.pack()
    self.entry_birthday.bind('<ButtonPress-1>',self.keyboard)

    self.label_civil_status = Label(self.master_register, text = "Civil Status")
    self.label_civil_status.pack()
    self.entry_civil_status = Entry(self.master_register, textvariable = self.civil_status)
    self.entry_civil_status.pack()
    self.entry_civil_status.bind('<ButtonPress-1>',self.keyboard)

    self.button_submit = Button(self.master_register, text = "Submit", command = lambda: self.registered(self.first_name, self.middle_name,
                                                                                        self.last_name, self.sex, self.birth_day,
                                                                                        self.civil_status))
    self.button_submit.pack()

def keyboard(self, event):
    exec(open("keyboardclass.py").read());
```

here is my keyboardclass.py

```
def select(value):
if value == "Space":
    entry1.insert(tkinter.END, ' ')
elif value == "Backspace":
    entry1.delete(len(entry1.get())-1,tkinter.END)
else:
    entry1.insert(tkinter.END, value)

root = Tk()
root.configure(background = "cornflowerblue")
root.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.7)

alphabets = ['`','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','-','=','<- 
   Backspace',
        'Tab','q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','[',']',"\\",
        'Caps Lock','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',';',"'",'Enter',
        'Shift','z','x','c','v','b','n','m',',','.','/','Shift',
         'Space']
Row = 2
Column = 0

for alphabet in alphabets:
command = lambda x=alphabet: select(x)
if alphabet != 'Space':
    Button(root, text = alphabet,
           command = command,width = 5, padx=3, pady=3,bd=12,bg = "black", fg="white").grid(row = Row, column = Column)
if alphabet == 'Enter':
    Button(root, text = alphabet,
           command = command, width = 15, padx=3, pady=3,bd=12,bg = "black", fg="white").grid(row = Row, column = Column, columnspan = 2)
if alphabet == 'Shift':
    Button(root, text = alphabet,
           command = command, width = 15, padx=3, pady=3,bd=12,bg = "black", fg="white").grid(row = Row, column = Column, columnspan = 2)    
if alphabet == 'Space':
    Button(root, text = alphabet,
           command = command, width = 130, padx=3, pady=3,bd=12,bg = "black", fg="white").grid(row = 6, columnspan = 16)

Column +=1
if Column > 13 and Row == 1:
    Column = 0
    Row += 1
if Column > 13 and Row == 2:
    Column = 0
    Row +=1
if Column > 13 and Row == 3:
    Column = 0
    Row +=1
if Column > 12 and Row == 4:
    Column = 0
    Row +=1
```

root.mainloop()

Comment: what do you have in `keyboardclass.py` ? Maybe you should change it and send `Entry` as parameter for keyboard so it could write directly to `Entry`. Long time ago was question with somehing similar. I don't remeber if I have code from those question on GitHub.

Comment: see [How to pop up an on screen keyboard to enter some data in an entry gadget in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161644/how-to-pop-up-an-on-screen-keyboard-to-enter-some-data-in-an-entry-gadget-in-tki).

Comment: I have a Tkinter GUI virtual keyboard in my keyboardclass.py. If I put the code in my keyboardclass.py It will not work, I mean I can get it done to type on entry but I'm producing a lot of line of codes since I'm assigning my virtual keyboard methods to every entry presented on my main GUI. That's why I've decided to just call the virtual keyboard from another program but I can't get it to type on my main program because it's separated.

Comment: I'll study what you gave me after school. I'm not getting enough sleep and so desperate to get this done. Since I'm not into programming, I'm not a fast learner, python is the only programming language that I know and I only started last month, but I'm doing my best. hoping to finish this week. Thank you so much! Your effort is really appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know what you have in `keyboardclass.py` but you should put it in function(s) and import it as any other module - `import keyboardclass` - and later run function(s) from this module - ie. `keyboardclass.show_keyboard()`. Function should get entry as parameter - ie. `keyboardclass.show_keyboard(self.entry_middle_name)` and use this entry inside function to put data.

Comment: Hi sir furas, I edited my post and post the keyboardclass.py. I will do what you said, I will import my keyboardclass to my main code. I put my keyboardclass just in case sir, Thank you so much!

Comment: I edited the code of my keyboardclass.py and made it simpler, but I can't get the logic on how my keyboard can type to my main code. I just create a trial code with 4 entries before putting it to my real code. `root = Tk()
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.pack()
entry2 = Entry(root)
entry2.pack()
entry3 = Entry(root)
entry3.pack()
entry3 = Entry(root)
entry3.pack()

try1231.select(entry1)`

try1231 is my new file name.
I don't know if I'm doing this correctly, I will also bind my widget to my virtual keyboard. I'm sorry to take too much of your time sir. I just really need help now.

Comment: hope you can give me a hint to solve this. I'm really desperate I'm so sorry sir furas.

Comment: in `keyboardclass` don't create Tk() (and rest) outside function. Put code in function(s) so  you could import it and run function in different moments to create keyboard. And you will need `select(entry, values)` instead of `select(value)`. Other problem is second `mainloop()` and second `Tk()` - `Tkinter` should have only one `mainloop()` because two mainloop make mess with values in variables. Keyboad should use `Toplevel` to create window and it shouldn't use `mainloop()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**keyboard.py**

I put code in function `create()` which gets `root` and `entry` as arguments - so now I can use `import keyboard` it other file and run `keyboard.create(root, some_entry)`.

It uses `root` to create  window `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` - and without second `mainloop()`.

It uses `entry` to use it in `select(entry, value)` which will use `entry.insert(...)`

There is code in `if __name__ == "__main__"`: so you can run it as standalone program to test keyboard.

It displays two `Entry` and one `Text` (in which you can test key `Enter`).

I added code for `Enter`, `Tab`, `Backspace` for `Text` (which needs different method). When you press `Shift` or `Caps Lock` then it starts to insert uppercase chars - but it doesn't change text on buttons in window.

In `alphabets` I grouped rows in lists so I don't need `if/else` to check if char should be in next row - I can use two `for`-loops.

---

```
import tkinter as tk

alphabets = [
    ['`','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','-','=','Backspace'],
    ['Tab','q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','[',']',"\\"],
    ['Caps Lock','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',';',"'",'Enter'],
    ['Shift','z','x','c','v','b','n','m',',','.','/','Shift'],
    ['Space']
]    

uppercase = False  # use uppercase chars. 

def select(entry, value):
    global uppercase

    if value == "Space":
        value = ' '
    elif value == 'Enter':
        value = '\n'
    elif value == 'Tab':
        value = '\t'

    if value == "Backspace":
        if isinstance(entry, tk.Entry):
            entry.delete(len(entry.get())-1, 'end')
        #elif isinstance(entry, tk.Text):
        else: # tk.Text
            entry.delete('end - 2c', 'end')
    elif value in ('Caps Lock', 'Shift'):
        uppercase = not uppercase # change True to False, or False to True
    else:
        if uppercase:
            value = value.upper()
        entry.insert('end', value)

def create(root, entry):

    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.configure(background="cornflowerblue")
    window.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.7)

    for y, row in enumerate(alphabets):

        x = 0

        #for x, text in enumerate(row):
        for text in row:

            if text in ('Enter', 'Shift'):
                width = 15
                columnspan = 2
            elif text == 'Space':
                width = 130
                columnspan = 16
            else:                
                width = 5
                columnspan = 1

            tk.Button(window, text=text, width=width, 
                      command=lambda value=text: select(entry, value),
                      padx=3, pady=3, bd=12, bg="black", fg="white"
                     ).grid(row=y, column=x, columnspan=columnspan)

            x += columnspan

# --- main ---

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Test Keyboard')

    label = tk.Label(root, text='Test Keyboard')
    label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

    entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
    entry1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='news')

    button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Keyboard', command=lambda:create(root, entry1))
    button1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='news')

    entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
    entry2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='news')

    button2 = tk.Button(root, text='Keyboard', command=lambda:create(root, entry2))
    button2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='news')

    text1 = tk.Text(root)
    text1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='news')

    button3 = tk.Button(root, text='Keyboard', command=lambda:create(root, text1))
    button3.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='news')

    root.mainloop()
```

---

**main.py**

It imports `keyboard` and uses `keyboard.create(...)` to show keyboard and assing it to selected `Entry` or `Text`.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
import keyboard

# --- main ---

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Hello World!')

    label = tk.Label(root, text='Form')
    label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

    #-----    

    label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Entry 1')
    label1.grid(row=1, column=0)

    entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
    entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='news')

    button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Keyboard', command=lambda:keyboard.create(root, entry1))
    button1.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='news')

    #-----    

    label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Entry 2')
    label2.grid(row=2, column=0)

    entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
    entry2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='news')

    button2 = tk.Button(root, text='Keyboard', command=lambda:keyboard.create(root, entry2))
    button2.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='news')

    #-----    

    label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Text 1')
    label3.grid(row=3, column=0)

    text1 = tk.Text(root)
    text1.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='news')

    button3 = tk.Button(root, text='Keyboard', command=lambda:keyboard.create(root, text1))
    button3.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='news')

    root.mainloop()
```

---

I was thinking to create widget which has Entry + Button `Keyboard` because you use this combination very often. Maybe I create it later.

Comment: Hi sir Furas, I tried your code and it's working perfectly. I will study every line of this code. Thank you so much! I've been solving this for almost a week. I am really grateful for your help. Without you, I will fail. Again, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
> import PySimpleGUI as py
> 
> statecolor = ['lightgrey', 'tan', 'yellow', 'lightblue', 'orange',
> 'limegreen', 'pink', 'red', 'darkgray'] py.theme('Python') key_setup =
> [[py.Text('Title')],
>              [py.Button('Q'), py.Button('W'), py.Button('E'), py.Button('R'), py.Button('T'), py.Button('Y')],
>              [py.Button('U'), py.Button('I'), py.Button('O'), py.Button('P'), py.Button('A'), py.Button('S')],
>              [py.Button('D'), py.Button('F'), py.Button('G'), py.Button('H'), py.Button('J'), py.Button('K')],
>              [py.Button('L'), py.Button('Z'), py.Button('X'), py.Button('C'), py.Button('V'), py.Button('B')],
>              [py.Button('N'), py.Button('Enter'), py.Button('M'), py.Button('Exit', button_color=('White', statecolor[7]), key='Exit')],
>              [py.Button('Space', button_color=('Red', statecolor[6]), key='Space')]] window = py.Window('Keyboard', key_setup) while True:
>     event, values = window.read()
>     if event == 'Q':
>         print('Q')
>     if event == 'W':
>         print('W')
>     if event == 'E':
>         print('E')
>     if event == 'R':
>         print('R')
>     if event == 'T':
>         print('T')
>     if event == 'Y':
>         print('Y')
>     if event == 'U':
>         print('U')
>     if event == 'I':
>         print('I')
>     if event == 'O':
>         print('O')
>     if event == 'P':
>         print('P')
>     if event == 'A':
>         print('A')
>     if event == 'S':
>         print('S')
>     if event == 'D':
>         print('D')
>     if event == 'F':
>         print('F')
>     if event == 'G':
>         print('G')
>     if event == 'H':
>         print('H')
>     if event == 'J':
>         print('J')
>     if event == 'K':
>         print('K')
>     if event == 'L':
>         print('L')
>     if event == 'Z':
>         print('Z')
>     if event == 'X':
>         print('X')
>     if event == 'C':
>         print('C')
>     if event == 'V':
>         print('V')
>     if event == 'B':
>         print('B')
>     if event == 'N':
>         print('N')
>     if event == 'M':
>         print('M')
>     if event == 'Enter':
>         print(' ')
>     if event == 'Exit':
>         break
>     if event == 'Space':
>         print('\b ', end="", flush=True)
>     if event == py.WIN_CLOSED:
>         exit() window.close()
> 
> Blockquote
```

Comment: What exactly is this?