# How to fix "Pymysql database not updating but you're not receiving any errors"

Tags: python, pymysql

I'm a registration module with details and RFID, but my database is not updating and I don't have any error.

I've seen similar problems with mine. They don't have a connection.commit() but mine already has a connection.commit() but still not updating.

```
self.db.commit()            
self.cursor.execute("UPDATE residence SET RFID = %s WHERE ID = %s", (id, self.db.insert_id()))
```

I expect the scanned RFID will be updated to the last inserted ID in my table.

Comment: `commit()` should be after `execute()`

Comment: Hi sir Furas, I did it but still the same.

Comment: first you could print values used in query and create query which you could test directly in database (using some database editor)

Comment: thank you sir, now I know my problem. The value of my db.insert_id() is 0 since I don't have an ID with a 0 value, it's not updating. But I searched to get the latest updated row and this is what I've got so why it is returning a 0 value?

Comment: `insert_id()` gives ID of row inserted in last `INSERT` query. You don't run any `INSERT` query before `UPDATE`

Comment: okay, sir, I understand now. Do you know how I can get my last row, I used  auto_increment ID.

Comment: to get last ID in database you could try `self.cursor.lastrowid`.

Comment: I tried it, but still not working. I printed the `self.cursor.lastrowid` and the output is 'None'

Comment: you can query like this `SELECT max(ID) IN residence`

Comment: I really appreciate your help sir Furas, you are the only person who answered my questions. I think I can solve this now since you game me a lot of ideas. I also studied the cups module you suggested to me last week. I really appreciate your help, but I'm getting desperate and really need to solve this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678492/typing-on-entry-using-virtual-keyboard-in-another-python-program. If you have some time. I hope you can give idea on how to get this done. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'll try it sir thank you so much!

Comment: I'm getting the last row when I used MySQL query, but when I code it. my database will update but not in my last row.